# infinite and uncountable structures in specific classes of structures

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, proof-theory

I'd appreciate your help with proofing one or both of the following statements:

1) let $M$ be an infinite countable structure. We want to show that there's an uncountable structure in $Mod(Th(M))$, whereby $Th(M)$ is the theory of $M$ (i.e. the set of all closed formulas $\phi$, which are fulfilled in every $\mathcal{M} \in M$). 
Hint: The completeness theorem and the compactness theorem do hold for uncountable languages, too. Use uncountably many constant symbols.

2) let $\Sigma$ be a theory (i.e. a set of closed formulas) with the following property: For every natural number n there's a natural number n' > n and a $\mathcal{M} \in Mod(\Sigma)$ with exactly n' elements. (whereby $Mod(\Sigma)$ is the class of all structures $\mathcal{M}$ (of a given language) that fulfill $\mathcal{M} \vDash \Sigma$). Show that there's an infinite structure in $Mod(\Sigma)$.

For 1) I don't know what to do.

For 2) I have the following idea: Assume there was no infinite structure in $Mod(\Sigma)$. Then there would have to be a maximal structure $\sigma \in Mod(\mathcal{M})$ (i.e. a structure with more elements than every other strucutre in $Mod(\Sigma)$ has). Let m be the number of its elements. Then there would be no structure $\sigma'$ in $Mod(\Sigma)$ with exactly m+1 elements, which is a contradiction to the property of $\Sigma$.

[Short question: Is the whole expression for $Mod(\Sigma)$, "Model for $\Sigma$" or what's it called?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can say that because there's no infinite structure, there is a maximal structure. In fact, that is pretty much what you're trying to prove. It's certainly conceivable at the outset that there could be a structure of every finite size, no matter how big, but no infinite structure.

The key to both problems is a compactness argument where you add a set of new constant symbols $\{c_i:i\in I\},$ as well as the axioms $c_i\ne c_j$ for all $i,j\in I.$ Then you show that every finite subtheory of this extended theory has a model by finding a model with more elements than $c_i$ that appear in the subtheory and assigning distinct elements to be interpretations of those $c_i.$ Then by compactness, the theory has a model, which by construction must have cardinality $\ge |I|.$

The notation $Mod(\Sigma)$ is not something I've seen very much (though even if you hadn't defined it, it would have been pretty clear from context what it was.) The most effecient expression I can think of is "the class of all models of $\Sigma$".

---

**edit**

I will explain the compactness argument in more detail, for the particular case of problem 2 (as I've said, 1 is very similar). Let $\Sigma$ be a $L$-theory that has models of every finite size. Now, let $\{c_i: i\in \mathbb N\}$ be a countably infinite collection of distinct constant symbols that do not appear in $L.$ Consider the extended language $L' = L\cup \{c_i: i\in \mathbb N\}$ and the $L'$-theory $$ \Sigma'=\Sigma \cup \{c_i\ne c_j: \mbox{$i,j\in \mathbb N$ and $i\ne j$}\}.$$

We claim $\Sigma'$ has a model. By compactness, it suffices to show that any finite subtheory of $\Sigma'$ is satisfiable. So let $\Sigma_0$ be such a finite subtheory. Then only a finite number $$ \{c_{i_k}:k\in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}\}$$ of the new constant symbols occur in $\Sigma_0.$ Then let $M$ be a model of $\Sigma$ with $n$ or more elements (which exists by hypothesis). Then $M$ becomes a model of $\Sigma_0$ when we interpret each of the $c_{i_k}$ as distinct elements of $M,$ since distinctness means it will satisfy any statement of the form $c_{i_k} \ne c_{i_{k'}}$ that might appear in $\Sigma_0.$

So let $N$ be a model of $\Sigma'.$ Clearly $N$ is a model of $\Sigma.$ We can also see that $N$ is infinite, since if it were finite, then one of the $c_i\ne c_j$ axioms in $\Sigma'$ would have to fail by pigeonhole.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But the whole thing is not clear to me yet. a) What do you mean by "you can't say "THAT""?  
b) Do you mean by "there's no infinite structure", that there is no countably infinite structure, too or that there's only no uncountably infinite structure? 
(If you mean the first, I don't get the difference between that for ever n there's a structure of size n and an infinite structure.) 
c) So statement 1) is wrong, isn't it? And is statement 2) true? Where did I make a mistake in my proof?

Comment: My first paragraph is a response to your attempt. You say “assume there was no infinite structure... then there would have to be a maximal structure.” I am saying that that isn’t correct reasoning... there could be arbitrarily large finite structures, but no infinite ones.

Comment: Oh I see, you are completely right, thanks! 
Could you be so kind as to explain your proof in more detail, please? I still don't understand it fully. And please let me know if 1) or 2) or both are true.

Comment: They are both true and have almost identical proofs using the compactness argument I described, the first with $I=\omega_1,$ and the second with $I=\omega.$ Do you see how the axioms $c_i\ne c_j$ collectively say “$|M|\ge |I|$”? The rest is showing there is a model of $\Sigma$ satisfying any finite subset of the axioms $c_i\ne c_j.$

Comment: I guess the idea is quite clear to me, but I don't understand the details. So let me repeat the steps and I add some questions: 

proof for 2): So we start with a theory $\Sigma$ with the property the exercise suggests. So we have a structure $\mathcal{M} \in Mod(\Sigma)$ that fulfills $\mathcal{M} \vDash \Sigma$ with exactly n elements. Tha language is given and the same for all structures in $Mod(\Sigma)$, so I don't know where to add the constants to. We also add axioms (to $\Sigma$, I guess?)

Comment: De interpretations of the constants in these added axioms have to be different from each other in order that these added axioms are correct. So there have to be at least as many elements as constant symbols in the universe of the structure that fulfills the extended theory. 

But what do we show for that every finite subtheory of this extended theory has a model? (Because we want to use the completeness theorem, I guess?) 

Sorry that the whole thing is still so unclear to me...

Comment: @Studentu I appended a more detailed explanation to the answer.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I nearly understand the proof now. The only thing I don't get yet is how we use the compactness theorem, because the version of the compactness theorem I know is the following: If $\Sigma \vDash \phi$, then there's a finite set $\Sigma' \subseteq \Sigma$ with $\Sigma' \vDash \phi$. And you seem to use an implication that goes the other way round?

Comment: @Studentu The form of the compactness theorem I use is that if $\Sigma$ is a theory such that every finite subtheory of $\Sigma$ has a model, then $\Sigma$ has a model. This can be seen to follow from the version you wrote by taking $\phi$ to be a contradiction.

Comment: I see. So with your version it is clear that the proof above works. However, I don't know how you mean this with the contradiction. 
If in my version we take $\phi$ to be a contradiction (so $\Sigma \vDash \phi \rightarrow \bot$ and therefore $\Sigma \vDash \bot$, I assume) we also have a finite set with $\Sigma' \vDash \bot$. And if we negate this and start from the other direction we get your version?

Comment: Or in other words: The point is that when $\Sigma \vDash \bot$, then also $\Sigma' \vDash \bot$, So if not $\Sigma' \vDash \bot$, then not $\Sigma \vDash \bot$ and therefore when $\Sigma' \vDash \phi$, then $\Sigma \vDash \phi$. 
Is this precise enough to be a proper proof?

Comment: @Studentu If you have $\bot,$ just let $\phi$ be $\bot.$ $\Sigma\models \bot$ means $\Sigma$ has no model, so your version of the compactness theorem implies “if $\Sigma$ has no model, then there is a finite subset $\Sigma’$ that has no model.” The statement I gave for the compactness theorem is the contrapositive of this.

Comment: Oh you are right, I lost track of the obvious. Thank you very much for all your help!